# Submitting a HIT with external URL throws error

Tags: python, xml, boto3

I am trying to submit a hit using the example provided in [mturk example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html)

Here is my question.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <ExternalURL>https://tictactoe.amazon.com/gamesurvey.cgi?gameid=01523</ExternalURL>
  <FrameHeight>750</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

and here is my submit_hit.py:

```
import boto3
from dateutil.parser import *
MTURK_SANDBOX = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
mturk = boto3.client('mturk',
   aws_access_key_id = "....",
   aws_secret_access_key = "....",
   region_name='us-east-1',
   endpoint_url = MTURK_SANDBOX
)
print "I have $" + mturk.get_account_balance()['AvailableBalance'] + " in my Sandbox account"

question = open(name='question.xml',mode='r').read()

new_hit = mturk.create_hit(
    Title = 'Here comes the title',
    Description = 'Here comes description'
    Keywords = 'game, quick',
    Reward = '0.15',
    MaxAssignments = 1,
    LifetimeInSeconds = 172800,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds = 600,
    AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds = 14400,
    Question = question,
)
print "A new HIT has been created. You can preview it here:"
print "https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=" + new_hit['HIT']['HITGroupId']
print "HITID = " + new_hit['HIT']['HITId'] + " (Use to Get Results)"
```

And here is the error I am receiving:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the CreateHIT operation: There was an error parsing the XML question or answer data in your request.  Please make sure the data is well-formed and validates against the appropriate schema. Details: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ExternalQuestion'. (1579649552886 s)
```

I need to use external url(i.e. I can not copy my html file in .xml) since my html content is web-based tool and not a simple questionare.
I am using python 2.7 if that matters.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question, but I believe asterisk imports are discouraged.

Comment: I removed that line, still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was using tag `<ExternalQuestion>`, BUT I was using the http link for `<HTMLQuestion>`! make sure you're using the right link.

So, instead of this:

`<ExternalQuestion 
 xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">`

it should be this:

`<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">`